# my function for filtering isnt working properly it dosent register first change in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

my filter function `filterFn` isnt working properly after using filter if i press backspace and remove all characters i dosent show all the departments also the `departmentId` filter dosent  filter if i press an id i have to press the number two times for it to work its like it dosent register the first inpunt of `onChange`

heres the code:

```
const Department = () => {


let [department, setDepartment] = useState([])
let [values, setValues] = useState({
    modalTitle: '',
    departmentName: '',
    departmentId: 0,

    departmentIdFilter: "",
    departmentNameFilter: "",
    departmentsWithoutFilter: [],
})

useEffect (() => {
    getDepartments()
}, [])

let filterFn = () =>{
    let departmentIdFilter = values.departmentIdFilter
    let departmentNameFilter = values.departmentNameFilter

    values.departmentsWithoutFilter = [...department]

    let filteredData = values.departmentsWithoutFilter.filter(
        function(el){
            return el.DepartmentId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                departmentIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
            ) &&
            el.DepartmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                departmentNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
            )

        }
    )
    setDepartment(filteredData)

}


let changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, 'departmentIdFilter': e.target.value})
    filterFn()
}


let changeDepartmentNameFilter = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setValues({...values, 'departmentNameFilter': e.target.value})
    filterFn()
}


let getDepartments = async () => {
    let response = await fetch (variables.API_URL + "department")
    let data = await response.json()

    setDepartment(data)
}


let changeDepartmentName = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, 'departmentName': e.target.value})
}

let addClick = () => {
    setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Add Department", departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
}

let editClick = (dep) => {
    setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Edit Department", departmentName: dep.DepartmentName, departmentId: dep.DepartmentId})
    console.log('default values', values)
    console.log(dep.DepartmentId)
}

let createClick = () => {
    fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            DepartmentName: values.departmentName
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        getDepartments()
        console.log(result)
        setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}


let updateClick = () => {
    fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            DepartmentId: values.departmentId,
            DepartmentName: values.departmentName
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        getDepartments()
        console.log(result)
        setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}


let deleteClick = (id) => {
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/"+id, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })


        .then(() => {
            getDepartments()
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
}

return (
    <div>

        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => addClick()}>Add Department</button>

        <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentIdFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                        DepartmentId
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentNameFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                        DepartmentName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Options
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {department.map((dep) => 

                    <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                        <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                        <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                        <td>
                            
                            {/* >>>>>>EDIT BUTTON<<<<<< */}
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(dep)}>
                                
                            </button>

                            {/* >>>>>>>DELETE BUTTON<<<<<<<<<<< */}
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                                
                            </button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    )}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title">{values.modalTitle}</h5>

                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                            <span className="input-group-text">Department Name</span>
                            <input name = 'departmentName' type="text" className="form-control" value={values.departmentName} onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentName(e)}} />
                            {/* <input type="text" className="form-control" value={departmentName} onChange={changeDepartmentName} /> */}
                        </div>

                        {values.departmentId == 0 ?
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => createClick()}>Create</button> :
                            null
                        }

                        {values.departmentId != 0 ?
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => updateClick()}>Edit</button> :
                            null
                        }

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
)
```

}

```
export default Department
```

Comment: I guess, use should use useEffect and value dependency to filter when value changed or add useCallback to filterFn, because set state does not apply immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filterFn():38, you're calling `setDepartment(filteredData)`, which overwrites the complete list of departments. Create a new list and use that in your view, avoid unnecessarily recreating the list fetched via an async query since that's an expensive operation.

Also, the reason your filter does not apply immediately is because you call filterFn() immediately after setValues:

```
 setValues({...values, 'departmentNameFilter': e.target.value})
 filterFn()
```

setValues is asynchronous, so it could happen way after filterFn() is called.

One way to get around this is to useEffect, which will trigger whenever values is updated:

```
useEffect(()=>{
filterFn()
}, [values])
```

Here's a full working version of your code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
const Department = () => {


let [department, setDepartment] = useState([])
let [filteredDepartments, setFilteredDepartment] = useState([])
let [values, setValues] = useState({
    modalTitle: '',
    departmentName: '',
    departmentId: 0,

    departmentIdFilter: "",
    departmentNameFilter: "",
    departmentsWithoutFilter: [],
})

useEffect (() => {
    getDepartments()
}, [])

useEffect (()=>{
      setFilteredDepartment(department)}, [department])

useEffect(()=>{
    filterFn()},[values])

let filterFn = () =>{
    let departmentIdFilter = values.departmentIdFilter
    let departmentNameFilter = values.departmentNameFilter

    values.departmentsWithoutFilter = [...department]

    let filteredData = values.departmentsWithoutFilter.filter(
        function(el){
            return el.DepartmentId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                departmentIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
            ) &&
            el.DepartmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                departmentNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
            )

        }
    )
    setFilteredDepartment(filteredData)

}


let changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, 'departmentIdFilter': e.target.value})
}


let changeDepartmentNameFilter = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setValues({...values, 'departmentNameFilter': e.target.value})
}


let getDepartments = async () => {
    let response = await fetch (variables.API_URL + "department")
    let data = await response.json()
}


let changeDepartmentName = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, 'departmentName': e.target.value})
}

let addClick = () => {
    setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Add Department", departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
}

let editClick = (dep) => {
    setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Edit Department", departmentName: dep.DepartmentName, departmentId: dep.DepartmentId})
    console.log('default values', values)
    console.log(dep.DepartmentId)
}

let createClick = () => {
    fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            DepartmentName: values.departmentName
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        getDepartments()
        console.log(result)
        setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}


let updateClick = () => {
    fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            DepartmentId: values.departmentId,
            DepartmentName: values.departmentName
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        getDepartments()
        console.log(result)
        setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}


let deleteClick = (id) => {
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/"+id, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })


        .then(() => {
            getDepartments()
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
}

return (
    <div>

        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => addClick()}>Add Department</button>

        <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentIdFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                        DepartmentId
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentNameFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                        DepartmentName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Options
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {filteredDepartments.map((dep) => 

                    <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                        <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                        <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                        <td>
                            
                            {/* >>>>>>EDIT BUTTON<<<<<< */}
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(dep)}>
                                
                            </button>

                            {/* >>>>>>>DELETE BUTTON<<<<<<<<<<< */}
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                                
                            </button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    )}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title">{values.modalTitle}</h5>

                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                            <span className="input-group-text">Department Name</span>
                            <input name = 'departmentName' type="text" className="form-control" value={values.departmentName} onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentName(e)}} />
                            {/* <input type="text" className="form-control" value={departmentName} onChange={changeDepartmentName} /> */}
                        </div>

                        {values.departmentId == 0 ?
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => createClick()}>Create</button> :
                            null
                        }

                        {values.departmentId != 0 ?
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => updateClick()}>Edit</button> :
                            null
                        }

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
)
                    }

function App() {
  return (
    <Department/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: if i put values as one of the dependencies it refreshes but shows the whole list everytime

Comment: what shows up in your list should only be the filteredDepartments. Be careful mutating that list unnecessarily. See the example in the answer, does it work for you?

Comment: sorry but it didnt work it shows an empty department screen

Comment: if its not to much of a problem can u please run this code i can provide u with the github link please

Comment: Not sure why it's giving you trouble, but it works here: https://replit.com/@SleepyStar/SnivelingHelpfulRectangle#src/App.jsx

Comment: yes this what i am trying to achive, can u please check this  https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js

Comment: See the code example I posted, you should create a new useEffect (separate from the the one where you call getDepartments() when the component loads. This new useEffect should look like: `useEffect(()=>{ filterFn(); },[values])`

Comment: `seEffect(()=>{  filterFn(); },[values])` just means "whenever values is updated, run this code"

Comment: Afterwards, you still have an issue where you override the department list everytime you call `  setDepartment(filteredData)` so you need to create a new filteredDepartments list and do setFilteredDepartments(filteredData).

Comment: having values as dependecy of useEffect is a bad idea because if things like modal title or department name is changed it will use the filterFn

Comment: then move those to a different state variable :)

Comment: i did as u said and made a new useEffect   `useEffect (()=>{
        filterFn()
    }, [values])`  it  just clears every item from department screen i even tried    `useEffect (()=>{
        filterFn()
    }, [values.departmentIdFilter, values.departmentNameFilter])`

Comment: Did you create a new list for filteredDepartments? You are overwriting the `department` list every time filterFn() is called atm

Comment: you are overwriting it here: https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js#L41

Comment: I encourage you to compare it with the sample code i provided

Comment: thanks sleepy before i was really tired and was understanding what u meant i took a break and red our discussion one more time and was able to fix the problem of results not showing after pressing backspace  thanks for your time and help

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that:

> For **input type='text'** elements, the **change** event doesn't fire until the control loses focus.

> Unlike the *input* event, the *change* event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

You might try replacing the **change** event with the **input** event.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. For example, please see the example on the official React docs, they use the onChange property to alter the state. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: still dosent register the first input